# Must declare the scalar variable which is a procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure if it doesn't already exists. This procedure takes a parameter of `date` type:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'GetAllManualInsertionsFromDate')

CREATE PROCEDURE volumetrie.GetAllManualInsertionsFromDate
    @date date
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT i.Id, i.EntryDate, c.CustomerNumber, i.NbEnvelopes As envelope, i.NbBoxes As box,
            c.Name, YEAR(@date) As dateYear, MONTH(@date) As dateMonth, s.Raccourci as area
    FROM volumetrie.InsertionManuelle As i
        INNER JOIN dbo.Customers As c ON i.ClientId = c.CustId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Sites s ON i.SiteCode = s.CodeSite
    WHERE i.EntryDate >= @date
END
```

I get an error on all three places where the @date parameter is used:

> Must declare the scalar variable @date

I also get another error on the `BEGIN` keyword, which may cause the other one:

> Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'. Expecting EXTERNAL.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Create procedure must be the only statement in a batch. That isn't what you have here. You either need to use your condition to drop the procedure if it already exists or use dynamic sql to generate your procedure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the dynamic SQL as an alternative in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'GetAllManualInsertionsFromDate')
drop procedure GetAllManualInsertionsFromDate
go

CREATE PROCEDURE volumetrie.GetAllManualInsertionsFromDate
    @date date
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT i.Id, i.EntryDate, c.CustomerNumber, i.NbEnvelopes As envelope, i.NbBoxes As box,
            c.Name, YEAR(@date) As dateYear, MONTH(@date) As dateMonth, s.Raccourci as area
    FROM volumetrie.InsertionManuelle As i
        INNER JOIN dbo.Customers As c ON i.ClientId = c.CustId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Sites s ON i.SiteCode = s.CodeSite
    WHERE i.EntryDate >= @date
END
```

- As @SeanLange said

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
-- =============================================
-- Create basic stored procedure template
-- =============================================

-- Drop stored procedure if it already exists
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
   WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = N'volumetrie'
     AND SPECIFIC_NAME = N'GetAllManualInsertionsFromDate' 
)
   DROP PROCEDURE volumetrie.GetAllManualInsertionsFromDate
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE volumetrie.GetAllManualInsertionsFromDate
    @date date
AS
    SELECT i.Id, i.EntryDate, c.CustomerNumber, i.NbEnvelopes As envelope, i.NbBoxes As box,
            c.Name, YEAR(@date) As dateYear, MONTH(@date) As dateMonth, s.Raccourci as area
    FROM volumetrie.InsertionManuelle As i
        INNER JOIN dbo.Customers As c ON i.ClientId = c.CustId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Sites s ON i.SiteCode = s.CodeSite
    WHERE i.EntryDate >= @date
GO
```

Comment: Why is that the correct way to check if a stored procedure exists? What's the difference with that I'm doing?

Comment: @BishopBarber this is how microsoft do it, try using template browser.